# Find the size/level of a node from its position within an quadtree

Tags: math, quadtree

I have a quadtree. The root node (level 0) is positioned at `0,0` by its centre. It has a width of 16, so its corners are at `-8,-8` and `8,8`. Since it's a quadtree, the root contains four children, each of which contain four children of their own and so on. The deepest level is level 3 at width 2. Here's a dodgy Paint drawing to better illustrate what I mean:

[image]

The large numbers indicate the centre position and width of each node. The small numbers around the sides indicate positions.

Given a valid position, how can I figure out what level or size of node exists at that position? It seems like this should be obvious but I can't get my head around the maths. I see the patterns in the diagram but I can't seem to translate it into code.

For instance, the node at position `1,1` is size 2/level 3. Position `4,6` is invalid because it's between nodes. Position `-6,-2` is size 4/level 2.

**Additional Notes:**

- Positions are addresses. They are exact and not worldspace, which is why it's possible to have an invalid address.
- In practice the root node size could be as large as 4096, or even larger.

Comment: Why is `4, 6` invalid? It should be size 8 / level 1 because it is still strictly inside the top right quadrant.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog It's invalid because while it's _inside_ a node, it's not the address of a node. There's no node centred on that exact location, in other words. I only use integers for my node addresses to reduce ambiguities like that which might arise from using floats, though as you can see I still have to be careful to calculate appropriate addresses. (Imagine that I gave you that position; which node would you return? The position is within an 8, exactly between two 4s and exactly in the middle of four 2s.)

Comment: Sounds like an incredibly arbitrary rule. Every single coordinate within (but not on) the outer boundary of the quad-tree should be a valid position. When using floats you would typically resolve conflicts with an epsilon; as you said, no such ambiguity exists for integers, so the logical choice should be the parent of the nodes that share the boundary. Then again, I don't claim to know the details of your specific use case.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog It's not arbitrary at all. I'm not trying to find a node by any arbitrary position within its bounds. The positions are addresses, which are exact and not worldspace. I can easily find a node by simply traversing the tree towards the given address. What I want, however, is a way to mathematically calculate what level of the tree a node would be at if it had a particular address. This allows me to iterate rather than recurse, since at that point I have a known maximum number of iterations required. This is both for performance and (greatly) reduced code complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the coordinate values for the centre of each node are always +/- **odd multiples of a power-of-2**, the latter being related to the node size:

```
Node size | Allowed centre coordinates | Factor
-----------------------------------------------------
    2     | 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 ...      | 1 = 2/2
-----------------------------------------------------
    4     | 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22 ...   | 2 = 4/2
-----------------------------------------------------
    8     | 4, 12, 20, 28, 36, 44 ...  | 4 = 8/2
-----------------------------------------------------
    16    | 8, 24, 40, 56, 72, 88 ...  | 8 = 16/2
```

The root node is a special case since it is always centred on `0,0`, but in a larger quad-tree the 16x16 nodes would follow the same pattern.

Crucially, both `X,Y` values of the coordinate must share the same power-of-2 factor. This means that the binary representations of their absolute values must have the **same number of trailing zeros**. For your examples:

```
Example | Binary | Zeros | Valid
----------------------------------
  X = 1 | 000001 |     0 |   Y
  Y = 1 | 000001 |     0 | S = 2
----------------------------------
  X = 4 | 000100 |     2 |   N
  Y = 6 | 000110 |     1 |
----------------------------------
  X =-6 | 000110 |     1 |   Y
  Y =-2 | 000010 |     1 | S = 4
```

Expressions for the desired results:

- Size (`S`) = 2 ^ (Zeros + 1)
- Level = [Maximum Level] - Zeros

Comment: This is a beautiful answer! Last night I struggled my way through to a trial-and-error method, doing address-mod-size (starting from the largest size) and checking for a zero result, but I didn't get as far as testing it before I went to bed. This is much more what I was looking for. I realised early on that the root node would likely be a special case, and I even wrote out various patterns of numbers to try to recognise how I could use those patterns, but I never would have seen the pattern in the binary representation. It's so elegant! This should be faster than mod, too. Thank you so much!